# Rsync over ssh: "ERROR: module is read only" suddenly appeared

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync, synology

I've used from some time rsync/ssh to backup my shared host contents to my personal Synology NAS (212j for that matter), and it worked quite well. 
For information, I use a password-less `ssh` connection.

3 days ago, I updated my NAS software and since (or at least I believe it's since that), the backup won't work anymore.
I get the following error on the host:

```
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
ERROR: module is read only
```

..which I do not understand. beside that nothing changed that I know of in both source and destination that can be related to `rsync` or `ssh`, I did check a few things and all seems to be alright:

- I can still connect through `ssh` from the host to my NAS with the good user, so ssh stuff like keys haven't changed.
- I also have the correct file permissions on the NAS (I checked, and also tried to create files, directories, .. with the user used by `rsync` through `ssh`).

I read here and there that the error means that I have to ensure that my `rsyncd.conf` have the right `read only = no` in it, but as far as I know, I never used `rsyncd` as well as I never configured anything for it and until now it worked like a charm..

I use the following command to do the backup:

```
rsync -ab --recursive \
--files-from="$FILES_FROM" \
--backup-dir=backup_$SUFFIX \
--delete \
--filter='protect backup_*' \
$WDIRECTORY/ \
remote_backup:$REMOTE_BACKUP/
```

So I'm stuck and really can't figure out what happened.

---

**Edit:**

As suggested in comments, I also tried passing commands to ssh (but not from inside a ssh session), that worked as expected, and also tried a single rsync command, which didnt worked, failing just like the complete backup command.

```
(sharedHost):hostuser:~ > touch test.txt
(sharedHost):hostuser:~ > rsync test.txt remote_backup:backups/test.txt
ERROR: module is read only
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1034) [Receiver=3.0.8]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

and

```
(sharedHost):hostuser:~ > ssh remote_backup 'touch /abs_path_to_backups/backups/test2.txt && echo "ProoF" > /abs_path_to_backups/backups/test2.txt'
(sharedHost):hostuser:~ > ssh remote_backup 'cat /abs_path_to_backups/backups/test2.txt'
ProoF
```

Comment: Try doing the remote update tests, but with commands given to ssh on the command line instead of through a ssh login session.  Also be sure the target space is not full.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I edited the question with their result. Also, the target space is not full at all (I was already sure, but I checked again)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating my Synology NAS to DSM 4.1. I also do rsync over SSH. In my situation using rsync user root@ip also worked but left the files on the server with owner root which I did not want.

I found in the NAS admin userinterface, that for some reason in ControlPanel->Users->MyRSyncUser->Edit->"Priviliges setup" there was no read/write access to the homes. My RSYNC destination is under the homes.

Setting this to privilidge worked for me. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much ! That worked ! Next time I update DSM, I'll double-check the permissions..

Comment: This seems to work if I use full path names (i.e., `rsync something nas:/volume2/homes/foo/bar/` instead of `rsync something nas:bar/`).

Comment: full path was the last step for me in annoying bout of debugging. thanks!

Comment: The problem with this solution (I've not found a better one) is that it gives the user privileges on all user homes, not just their own.

Comment: In my case (with a newer version I assume), I also had to change to module based syntax ( see https://superuser.com/questions/559047/cant-rsync-locally-on-synology-nas/1532718#1532718 )

Comment: I had this problem, but it wasn't caused by permissions, but simply by misspelling the remote path. the Synology rsync will not tell you that -- just that the path you specify is "read only"

Comment: Mine was a similar issue as @dovetalk. Except I didnt mispell so much as using the wrong case. ie, Trying to pull files from a remote path of /Volume1/etc.. when it should have been /volume1/etc..

Answer (score 14):

I got rid of ERROR: module is read only by changing the remote path from /var/services/homes/rsync to /volume2/homes/rsync

DSM 5.1

Comment: Yes this worked for me too: You definitely need the volume in the DiskStation path:
 USERNAME@DiskStation:/volume1/somebackupDir    works,

USERNAME@DiskStation:/somebackupDir    gives error

`receiving incremental file list
ERROR: module is write only
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(782) [sender=3.0.9]`

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem after upgrading a synology ds1010+ to dsm 4.1-2661.

I don't have the time to understand what happened to the rsync provided by synology but it does not seem standard. 
So here is my workaround...

I didn't want to hack the privileges (multi-user setup), so I've recompiled rsync in static on my laptop, then I've transfered the binary on the sinology nas.

```
wget https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync-3.0.9.tar.gz
tar xzvf rsync-3.0.9.tar.gz
cd rsync-3.0.9
export CFLAGS=--static
./configure
make

scp rsync <login>@<nas_hostname>:
```

You can tell rsync to use your new binary instead of the default one, with this parameter:

```
--rsync-path=<myhome>/rsync
```

Now I can continue using duplicity with rsync, by adding the following parameter to duplicity:

```
--rsync-options="--rsync-path=<myhome>/rsync"
```

Comment: This is what I did with my DS212j, except I used ipkg to install the new rsync.  Synology's directions for installing ipkg are [here](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Overview_on_modifying_the_Synology_Server,_bootstrap,_ipkg_etc#for_compiled.2Fbinary_programs).

Comment: I couldn't find anything on ipkg for DSM 5.2, so for my DS215j I did as follows to compile (I already had the cross-compiler arm-unknown-eabi-gcc lying around) `./configure --host=armv7 CFLAGS=-static EXEEXT=-static --prefix=/opt CC=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc && make && arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-strip rsync && make DESTDIR=$PWD/../prefix install`. Put the binary in /opt/bin/ on the NAS. Also have to give my backup user a shell in /etc/passwd by changing /sbin/nologin to /bin/sh (There should be some more secure options).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of issue, but I wasn't using a dedicated user for rsync.

I had to fix privileges in Control Panel -> Shared folders.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while connecting to Synology 211j over Putty's ssh. I had to enable

"Control Panel -> Network backup -> Enable network backup service".

It is working now.

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by logging in as root instead of admin or regular user.